# How do you setup Raspbian Stretch as wireless-only router with Internet access?

Tags: wireless-networking, hostapd, stretch

## The Situation

Raspbian Stretch is wirelessly connected to a private subnet 10.0.0.0/16 via wlan0 (model RT5370). Without further modification, Raspbian Stretch has Internet access and DNS is working. PS: I don't have physical access to the router that connects to the Internet - only wireless.

I added another RT5370 NIC as wlan1 and set it up as a wireless access point using hostapd.

Because I don't know the router's DHCP server address range, I don't want to add a static address to wlan0.

I have configured a static IPv4 address on wlan1 192.168.0.1/28 (16 host addresses) and I setup dnsmasq to be the DHCP server for this network.

## The Problem

It should be pretty simple really.

Raspbian Stretch can either 1) access the Internet or 2) act as a WAP to connect clients. The problem is that both features won't work at the same time.

I've seen guides where the Internet connection is established via copper instead of radio-waves but I don't see why it makes any difference if the Internet connected interface is wireless instead of wired. Anyways...

## What I've Tried

On a fresh reboot, I can ping google.com and 8.8.8.8 successfully.

I can see both wlan0 and wlan1 after checking `ifconfig` and they seem to be setup ok.

Here's the output of `route`.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway     Genbask         Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
default     10.0.0.36   0.0.0.0         UG    303    0     0 wlan0
default     192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0         UG    304    0     0 wlan1
10.0.0.0    0.0.0.0     255.255.0.0     U     303    0     0 wlan0
192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0     255.255.255.240 U     303    0     0 wlan1
```

I don't know why it looks like two default gateways are here when a single default route seems more appropriate but the Internet works so I continue...

After proving Raspbian Stretch has Internet access, I try:

```
root@computer:/# hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

And get this:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: driver initialization failed.
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
```

Now, interestingly, after I do:

```
root@computer:/# killall wpa_supplicant
root@computer:/# hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf &
```

I get this:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Using interface wlan1 with hwaddress aa:bb:cc:11:22:33 and ssid "myssid"
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlan1: AP-ENABLED
```

This allows me to successfully connect client machines to myssid via wlan1 but now I can't ping google.com or 8.8.8.8 and I noticed wlan0 isn't showing in ifconfig and my routing table looks like this now:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway     Genbask         Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0     255.255.255.240 U     303    0     0 wlan1
```

To get wlan0 back up I do:

```
root@computer:/# service dhcpcd restart
root@computer:/# sysctl daemon-reload
```

Now wlan0 and wlan1 are showing up in ifconfig, Raspbian Stretch can ping google.com and 8.8.8.8, but clients connected to wlan1 have no Internet access.

At this point my routing table looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway     Genbask         Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
default     10.0.0.36   0.0.0.0         UG    303    0     0 wlan0
10.0.0.0    0.0.0.0     255.255.0.0     U     303    0     0 wlan0
192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0     255.255.255.240 U     304    0     0 wlan1
```

If only I could allow wlan1 clients Internet access, this could all be over :)

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no route from the Internet gateway router to the network attached to wlan1 (192.168.0.0/28),  I ended up just setting up dynamic NAT with PAT overload between wlan0 and wlan1.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Mission Accomplished!

If I had access to the Internet gateway router, I could probably add a static route from Raspbian Stretch's wlan0 address to the 192.168.0.0/28 network but 1) I don't have access to that router and 2) I'd also have to setup either - a) a DHCP reservation on the DHCP server (which I also don't have access to) or b) a static IP address on Raspbian Stretch's wlan0 - if I wanted to avoid making changes when the wlan0 dhcp ease expires. So a static route won't work in this case.

Anyway, this is the first working router/firewall I've seen or heard of that does *NOT* use a wired connection to the WAN *OR* the LAN.

People could totally use this on an open free WiFi network instead of using a VPN or SOCKS proxy (if you know enough about iptables to secure your connection.)